# Catching the user entering a string when expecting an integer?

Tags: c, scanf, user-input

I am making a program where the user enters two binary numbers and an operation character then I print the output in decimal.  I want the while loop to keep the program running until the user enters quit.  How can I read if the user enters quit and not an integer value in the scanf?  Is there a way to catch this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int toDecimal(int num);

int main(){
    // Define variables
    int num1, num2, result = 0;
    char op;
    char run[4] = "go";

    // While loop to rerun program until quit is entered
    while(strcmp(run, "quit\n") != 0){
        // Reads user input
        scanf("%i %c %i", run, &num1, &op, &num2);



        printf("\nnum1: %i num2: %i op: %c\n", num1, num2, op);

        num1 = toDecimal(num1);
        num2 = toDecimal(num2);
        printf("\nnum1: %i num2: %i op: %c\n", num1, num2, op);

    }
    printf("\nGoodbye!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I believe that I may be able to read everything in as a string and then convert to an integer however I don't know how.  Is this a solution I should look into?

Comment: you can use atoi to convert from a string to integer.

Comment: You could read a full input line with `fgets` into a buffer. You can then test if the content of the buffer is "quit\n". If it's not, you can then use `sscanf` to scan the content of the buffer. Another method is to test the return value of your `scanf`. If it's 0, the input doesn't start with a number. You can the use a `scanf(" %s")` to read the input string and compare it with "quit".

Comment: `"quit\n"` is a 6 character size string.  With `char run[4]`, how do you ever expect `strcmp(run, "quit\n")` to be 0?

Comment: @chmike Suggesting `scanf(" %s", ...)` is like suggesting `gets()`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica it's not exactly the same. Scanf will only take a word stopping at space. Gets would take the full line. Beside gets is deprecated in C11.

Comment: The problem is that you can't enforce what the user actually types into `stdin` even if you expect a certain format in `scanf`.

Comment: You have `scanf("%i %c %i", run, &num1, &op, &num2);` — you pass four argument and convert three values.  That will not lead to happiness.  You should check that the return value from `scanf()` is 3 (since you have 3 conversions).  But you'd probably do best using (and checking) `fgets()` to read a line and then using `sscanf()` to parse it, and testing the return value from `sscanf()` — always check inputs.

Comment: @chmike Yes `gets()` and `scanf(" %s", ...)` are both equally bad as the are subject to buffer overflow.

Comment: Jacob, "... a program where the user enters two binary numbers and an operation character " --> Always more helpful to post some example input and expected output.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I read if the user enters quit and not an integer value in the scanf?

There is no good way with `scanf()`.  Instead get user input with `fgets()` and do not use `scanf()` until you know why it is bad.

```
// Read user input
char buf[80]; // Use adequate size input buffer,
while (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
  buf[strcspn(buf, "\n")] = '\0'; // Lop off potential trailing \n

  if (sscanf(bufm "%i %c %i", &num1, &op, &num2) == 3) {
    printf("\nnum1: %i num2: %i op: %c\n", num1, num2, op);
    num1 = toDecimal(num1);
    num2 = toDecimal(num2);
    printf("\nnum1: %i num2: %i op: %c\n", num1, num2, op);
  } else if (strcmp(buf, "quit")== 0) {
    break;
  } else {
    printf("Bad input <%s> ignored\n", buf);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty basic idea , I hope you get the point.You could also use dynamic memory allocation when reading the string.

Basically you read the whole input with **fgets** and you extract the variables using **sscanf**.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
int n1,n2;
char arr[1000],oper;

fgets(arr,sizeof(arr),stdin);
 while (strcmp(arr,"quit\n")!=0){
    if (sscanf(arr,"%d %c %d",&n1,&oper,&n2)==3); /* Scanning for each number and operator and checking input*/
    else
    printf("wrong input");
/*  Code */
    fgets(arr,sizeof(arr),stdin);
    }
return 0;
}
```